# Why aren't my variables displaying in the Vscode debugger while I'm trying to debug my Python code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, variables, debugging, vscode-debugger

I was attempting to debug my python code in Vscode, but the variables and watch sections did not display anything.

I tried checking over my code to see if that was the problem but I'm sure there are variables that should be showing up.

Comment: Try adding a screenshot or something to help people help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you have set a **breakpoint** in the file, otherwise it will run the file directly to the end without displaying any information.

You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) for more details about debugging in Python.